# MY SQL Foreign Key Constraint Error

Tags: mysql

I m using MySQL database as back end for my application. I was playing with database and i did something wrong couple of days ago and now i am not able to apply foreign key on my DB Table.
I have 2 tables shoplocation and pizaorderdetail. In pizzaordrdetail i am passing id from shoplocation as foreign key. And i am getting following error. The table already contains data in it. And earlier i had foreign key constraint available on pizzaorderdetail but somehow it got deleted. Please help me out how to resolve this error.

Executing:
ALTER TABLE `order`.`pizzaorderdetail` 
ADD INDEX `FK_idx` (`LocationID` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `order`.`pizzaorderdetail` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK`
  FOREIGN KEY (`LocationID`)
  REFERENCES `order`.`location` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`order`.`#sql-714_31`, CONSTRAINT `FK` FOREIGN KEY (`LocationID`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `order`.`pizzaorderdetail` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK`
  FOREIGN KEY (`LocationID`)
  REFERENCES `order`.`location` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Comment: I have found  temporary solution by disabling foreign key check then apply constraint and apply foreign key check again. Is it the right approach ?

Comment: If the data in the tables is correct, then is a type issue. Try checking the id in both tables. (same type, length, unsigned...). They should be exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your FK is ok. When I recieved this message, I just deleted my FK's and it was solved.

According to manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html

> InnoDB reports this error when you attempt to drop the last index that
>   can enforce a particular referential constraint.
>
> For optimal performance with DML statements, InnoDB requires an index
>   to exist on foreign key columns, so that UPDATE and DELETE operations
>   on a parent table can easily check whether corresponding rows exist in
>   the child table. MySQL creates or drops such indexes automatically
>   when needed, as a side-effect of CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX, and ALTER
>   TABLE statements.
>
> When you drop an index, InnoDB checks if the index is used for
>   checking a foreign key constraint. It is still OK to drop the index if
>   there is another index that can be used to enforce the same
>   constraint. InnoDB prevents you from dropping the last index that can
>   enforce a particular referential constraint.